# Needing another pair of eyes to check my work? Scientific Lab Report

Tags: report

I have been trying to copy and rework [this](https://www.overleaf.com/project/5f0cc409d15dc1000174db00) template into my own Lab report. However, when I try to do so I have gotten an error. What can I do to fix this? Also, what can I do to add a Data Table with a corresponding table, Data Analysis, and Results section? I am still learning the ins and outs of LaTeX, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{olplainarticle}
% Use option lineno for line numbers 

\title{Example Article Title}

\author[1]{First Author}
\author[2]{Second Author}
\affil[1]{Address of first author}
\affil[2]{Address of second author}

\keywords{Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3}

\begin{abstract}
Please provide an abstract of no more than 300 words. Your abstract should explain the main contributions of your article, and should not contain any material that is not included in the main text. 
\end{abstract}

\begin{document}

\flushbottom
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section*{Introduction}

Thanks for using Overleaf to write your article. Your introduction goes here! Some examples of commonly used commands and features are listed below, to help you get started.

\section*{Methods and Materials}

Guidelines can be included for standard research article sections, such as this one.

\section*{Some \LaTeX{} Examples}
\label{sec:examples}

Use section and subsection commands to organize your document. \LaTeX{} handles all the formatting and numbering automatically. Use ref and label commands for cross-references.

\subsection*{Figures and Tables}

Use the table and tabular commands for basic tables --- see Table~\ref{tab:widgets}, for example. You can upload a figure (JPEG, PNG or PDF) using the project menu. To include it in your document, use the includegraphics command as in the code for Figure~\ref{fig:view} below.

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{frog}
\caption{An example image of a frog.}
\label{fig:view}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|r}
Item & Quantity \\\hline
Candles & 4 \\
Fork handles & ?  
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:widgets}An example table.}
\end{table}

\subsection*{Citations}

LaTeX formats citations and references automatically using the bibliography records in your .bib file, which you can edit via the project menu. Use the cite command for an inline citation, like \cite{lees2010theoretical}, and the citep command for a citation in parentheses \citep{lees2010theoretical}.

\subsection*{Mathematics}

\LaTeX{} is great at typesetting mathematics. Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with $\text{E}[X_i] = \mu$ and $\text{Var}[X_i] = \sigma^2 < \infty$, and let
$$S_n = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n}{n}
      = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^{n} X_i$$
denote their mean. Then as $n$ approaches infinity, the random variables $\sqrt{n}(S_n - \mu)$ converge in distribution to a normal $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$.

\subsection*{Lists}

You can make lists with automatic numbering \dots

\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep] 
\item Like this,
\item and like this.
\end{enumerate}
\dots or bullet points \dots
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep] 
\item Like this,
\item and like this.
\end{itemize}
\dots or with words and descriptions \dots
\begin{description}
\item[Word] Definition
\item[Concept] Explanation
\item[Idea] Text
\end{description}

\section*{Acknowledgments}

Additional information can be given in the template, such as to not include funder information in the acknowledgments section.

\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Knowing that would make proofreading easier for everyone.

Comment: Your link to Overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/project/5f0cc409d15dc1000174db00) is not publicly accessible.

Comment: Hello Fiat96, and TobiBS!, the error that I am getting in Sublime Text 3 is "LaTeX Error: File 'olplainarticle.cls" is not found. []

Comment: @LittleRedHelper Well if you get this error, then `oldplainarticle.cls` is not part of you TeX distribution. Either you continue with my example in the answer, which doesn't require this class, or you find it!

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how your class `oldplainarticle` looks, but I guess your biggest issue is the `abstract` environment before the `\begin{document}`. I tried to mimic all other commands and besides the issue with the missing citation references, this is what works for me without knowing your class:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{article}
% Use option lineno for line numbers 

\usepackage{graphicx,enumitem}

\newcommand{\citep}[1]{(\cite{#1})}
\newcommand{\text}[1]{\mbox{#1}}

\title{Example Article Title}

\author{First Author\thanks{Address 1}, Second Author\thanks{Address 2}}
%\affil[1]{Address of first author}
%\affil[2]{Address of second author}

%\keywords{Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Please provide an abstract of no more than 300 words. Your abstract should explain the main contributions of your article, and should not contain any material that is not included in the main text. 
\end{abstract}

\flushbottom
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section*{Introduction}

Thanks for using Overleaf to write your article. Your introduction goes here! Some examples of commonly used commands and features are listed below, to help you get started.

\section*{Methods and Materials}

Guidelines can be included for standard research article sections, such as this one.

\section*{Some \LaTeX{} Examples}
\label{sec:examples}

Use section and subsection commands to organize your document. \LaTeX{} handles all the formatting and numbering automatically. Use ref and label commands for cross-references.

\subsection*{Figures and Tables}

Use the table and tabular commands for basic tables --- see Table~\ref{tab:widgets}, for example. You can upload a figure (JPEG, PNG or PDF) using the project menu. To include it in your document, use the includegraphics command as in the code for Figure~\ref{fig:view} below.

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{An example image of a frog.}
\label{fig:view}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|r}
Item & Quantity \\\hline
Candles & 4 \\
Fork handles & ?  
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:widgets}An example table.}
\end{table}

\subsection*{Citations}

LaTeX formats citations and references automatically using the bibliography records in your .bib file, which you can edit via the project menu. Use the cite command for an inline citation, like \cite{lees2010theoretical}, and the citep command for a citation in parentheses \citep{lees2010theoretical}.

\subsection*{Mathematics}

\LaTeX{} is great at typesetting mathematics. Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with $\text{E}[X_i] = \mu$ and $\text{Var}[X_i] = \sigma^2 < \infty$, and let
$$S_n = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n}{n}
      = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^{n} X_i$$
denote their mean. Then as $n$ approaches infinity, the random variables $\sqrt{n}(S_n - \mu)$ converge in distribution to a normal $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$.

\subsection*{Lists}

You can make lists with automatic numbering \dots

\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep] 
\item Like this,
\item and like this.
\end{enumerate}
\dots or bullet points \dots
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep] 
\item Like this,
\item and like this.
\end{itemize}
\dots or with words and descriptions \dots
\begin{description}
\item[Word] Definition
\item[Concept] Explanation
\item[Idea] Text
\end{description}

\section*{Acknowledgments}

Additional information can be given in the template, such as to not include funder information in the acknowledgments section.

\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello TobiBS! I just tried copying the code on overleaf myself onto Sublime Text 3 and I am getting the error code as well. I am not sure what to do and what to work on?

Comment: @LittleRedHelper the only error you should get is that `lees2010theoretical` is not defined. Can you please post the error you are getting?

Comment: The code is working just fine for me now, but the only real problem is that now I have to change the "abstract" section to match the other sections, numbering the procedures, and creating a table x by x grid in the Data Table section, any thoughts?  I copied and pasted your code, and didn't any errors that you are talking about.

Comment: @LittleRedHelper I think it would be best if you show, what you want to achieve through a drawing, a sketch or similar and from there we can start and maybe it makes sense for you to open specific questions for each specific issue.

Comment: Okay, I'll be sure to give a picture of what I am trying to achieve here.